# Zeus returning warning for a parallel rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, zeus, parallel-testing

I'm trying to make my rails development process faster with zeus. So, I installed `zeus` & `parallel_tests` gems. All of them working good, but when I'm trying to connect this to gems via `zeus-parallel_tests` gem, I get this annoying warnings every operation. What can I do to avoid this warnings?

```
$ zeus parallel_rspec spec/
4 processes for 17 specs, ~ 4 specs per process
Warning: Specifying a Rails environment via RAILS_ENV has no effect for commands run with zeus.
Warning: Specifying a Rails environment via RAILS_ENV has no effect for commands run with zeus.
Warning: Specifying a Rails environment via RAILS_ENV has no effect for commands run with zeus.
Warning: Specifying a Rails environment via RAILS_ENV has no effect for commands run with zeus.
Tests run here
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unset your `RAILS_ENV` environment variable, to make zeus stop complaining.

You can achieve this by temporarily unsetting it for the `zeus` command:

```
$ RAILS_ENV='' zeus parallel_rspec spec/
```

If you want to set the environment variable permanently, you can export it from your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`:

```
$ echo RAILS_ENV='' >> ~/.profile'
```

To make your environment pick up the change, you will need to "source" it: `$ source ~/.profile`.